# LINQPad and System.Net tracing

Tags: httpwebrequest, linqpad, trace, system.net

I am trying trace a LINQPad script. I have setup System.Net tracing according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty48b824.aspx.

I have put following lines into the `LINQPad.exe.config` file:

```
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.Net" tracemode="includehex" maxdatasize="1024">
        <listeners>
          <add name="System.Net"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.Net.Sockets">
        <listeners>
          <add name="System.Net"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.Net.Cache">
        <listeners>
          <add name="System.Net"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <switches>
      <add name="System.Net" value="Verbose"/>
      <add name="System.Net.Sockets" value="Verbose"/>
      <add name="System.Net.Cache" value="Verbose"/>
    </switches>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="System.Net"
        type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
        initializeData="network.log"
      />
    </sharedListeners>
    <trace autoflush="true"/>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

The `network.log` file is created. It contains the logs from the LINQPad version check:

```
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [1220] WebClient#3359025::DownloadString(http://www.linqpad.net/updates40/version.txt)
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [1220] WebClient#3359025::DownloadData(http://www.linqpad.net/updates40/version.txt)
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [1220] WebRequest::Create(http://www.linqpad.net/updates40/version.txt)
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [1220] HttpWebRequest::HttpWebRequest(http://www.linqpad.net/updates40/version.txt)
...
```

However after running the LINQPad script that is using a WebRequest to download a url, this request is not logged.

Why the LINQPad scripts are not logged? Is it possible to log them? If so, how?

Comment: Did you try adding these line to LinqPad.config rather than Linqpad.exe.config  ?

Comment: No. You can put this into the answer, it helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use LinqPad.config rather than Linqpad.exe.config

From http://www.linqpad.net/FAQ.aspx

> I'm referencing a custom assembly that reads settings from an application configuration file (app.config). Where should I put my application config file so that LINQPad queries will pick it up?
>
> Into a file called linqpad.config. This is explained in detail [here](http://coding.infoconex.com/post/2012/06/01/Getting-LINQPad-to-read-your-applications-AppConfig-settings.aspx).